# Unit Testing a Retrieve TableOperation for Azure Table Storage

Tags: c#, azure, unit-testing, moq, azure-table-storage

I have some code that I'd like to unit test.
I am retrieving some data from an Azure Storage Table database as part of my method that I'd like to test, so I need to mock out the return from the database.

**Code to test:**

```
public class GetCustomer : IGetCustomer
{
   //constructor
   public GetCustomer(IClientTableFactory clientTableFactory)
   {
      _partitionKey = "test";
      _customersTable = clientTableFactory.GetStorageTable("customers");
   }

   //method to test
   public async Task<string> GetCustomerNameAsync(string email)
   {
      //match on full email
      var match = await SearchAsync(email.ToLower());
      if (match == null)
      {
         //just match on email domain
         var domain = email.ToLower().Substring(email.IndexOf("@"));
         match = await SearchAsync(domain);
      }
      return match;
   }

   //internal method that queries Azure Table Storage
   private async Task<string> SearchAsync(string searchString)
   {
      var query = TableOperation.Retrieve<Customer>(_partitionKey, rowkey: searchString);
      var result = await _customersTable.ExecuteAsync(query);
      var match = result.Result as Customer;
      return match?.Name;
   }
}
```

**Unit Test so far:**

```
//Arrange
var email = "Testy.McTest@Test.com.au";
var tableFactory = new Mock<IClientTableFactory>();
var customersTable = new Mock<CloudTable>(new Uri("http://unittests.localhost.com/FakeTable"));
customersTable.Setup(x => x.ExecuteAsync(It.IsAny<TableOperation>()))
   .ReturnsAsync(new TableResult{ HttpStatusCode = 200, Result = new Customer{ Name = "jiminy crickets" }});
tableFactory.Setup(x => x.GetStorageTable("customers")).Returns(customersTable.Object);
var getCustomers = new GetCustomer(tableFactory.Object);
// Act
var result = await getCustomers.GetCustomerNameAsync(email);
// Assert
Assert.AreEqual("jiminy crickets", result);
```

Of course, the test passes every time. The missing piece of the puzzle that I would like to mock out is this line:

```
customersTable
    .Setup(x => x.ExecuteAsync(It.IsAny<TableOperation>()))
    .ReturnsAsync...
```

I should be able to replace `It.IsAny<TableOperation>()` with my search query eg `It.Is<TableOperation>(y => y.RowKey == "testy.mctest@test.com.au"` but unfortunately RowKey is inaccessible.

I've also tried

```
customersTable
    .Setup(x => x.ExecuteAsync(TableOperation.Retrieve<Customer>(_partitionKey, rowkey: searchString))
```

but it never passes this code at runtime - maybe because of the `ETag` property?

Any ideas? I've seen plenty of answers about mocking Table Storage, but none about mocking Query results.

Comment: It is a bit confusing what you are trying to do in that match expression since `RowKey` is within the entity and not the operation.

Comment: @nkosi The match expression is to retrieve a single entity by partition key + row key.

Comment: The issue seems to me to be that you are trying to mock a static method.  You can shim that, I have some code for that somewhere.  I don't think that is a good idea, you have to mark your project as unsafe and you swap memory addresses.  

You could moq it to return in  the results in a certain order. https://haacked.com/archive/2009/09/29/moq-sequences.aspx/

Comment: Is TableOperation static? If so maybe wrap it in a class and inject it, that way you can mock it more easily...

Comment: Table operation the class is not but the public methods are.  I totally agree with the wrapping, I would even argue that it should be a separate interface and implementation that would wrap table storage as a repository.  That felt out of scope but mocking that would be a lot easier.

Comment: I'm trying to do this exact same thing, I can't work it out. In the Retrieve operation, I want Assert that the partitionkey and rowkey are what they're suppose to be. But it seems to be impossible because RetrievePartitionKey and RetrieveRowKey are private.

Comment: @BG100 let me know if you work it out. I ended up going with the moq verify method instead, just to verify that the method was called, without checking the results :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind using reflection you can find the values in the internal members "RetrievePartitionKey" and "RetrieveRowKey".

I wrote a simple method:

```
  private T GetInternalMember<T>(object obj, string propertyName)
    {
        Type objType = obj.GetType();
        PropertyInfo propInfo = objType.GetProperty(propertyName,
                BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

        return (T)propInfo.GetValue(obj, null);
    }
```

And I'm using it like:

```
cloudTable.Verify(x => x.ExecuteAsync(It.Is<TableOperation>(op => GetInternalMember<string>(op, "RetrievePartitionKey") == "TestPartitionKey"
                                                                           && GetInternalMember<string>(op, "RetrieveRowKey") == "TestRowKey")));
```

It's not really ideal, but it works for unit tests.